# Vectorize Indexing first n elements

Tags: python, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize the following for-loop

```
for n in range(N):
  x = np.empty(n)
  x = array[:n]
  #do something with x
```

In particular I would like to use something like

```
x = np.empty(shape = [N, range(N)])    
x[:] = array[:range(N)]
#do something with x
```

but obviously this doesen't work. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The solution will depend on what you want to do with x.  numpy cannot process variable size dimensions so, unless your calculations can ignore some items by themselves, you'll need a for loop and there won't be much you can vectorize.

Comment: You may consider using a pandas DataFrame and use : pandas.DataFrame.apply(...) ?